# Has anyone tried the Lenovo USB 3.0 Dock on Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware

I'm thinking on buying the Lenovo USB 3.0 Dock and use it with Ubuntu and Unity, but I haven't found information regarding if Ubuntu already has built-in drivers for it.

The link to this product is this one:

http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=460&Code=0A33970#overview

So, I'd just like to know if its a good idea getting it or I'd better not because I might have a difficult time trying to set it up.

Thanks.

Comment: I bought one of these docks without doing my research and the display didn't work. But now Displaylink has provided an Ubuntu driver. I installed it following the directions at http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu and it now works!

Comment: happy to see that I am not the only one struggling with this problem. A quick solution for the ethernet problem: Just connect to the docking station via a LAN-to-USB adapter. I have a Carbon X1 4rd Generation with Ubuntu 18.04 and a OneLink+. Compiling the ethernet driver did not work for some reason I couldn't figure out. Best,
Tristan

Answer (score 14):

**Edit August 2015**

There is a beta driver now to support USB3 docks. See the linked forum for details.

**Edit January 2016**
Out of the box working:

- HDMI
- Sound (depending on your device change soundcard output)
- USB (front and back)
  With installed driver working:
- Ethernet
  https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Onelink-Dock-and-Linux-support/td-p/1346267

**Original answer**

The video of the dock is not supported under Linux, and will not be for a longer time.
The dock uses a DL3XXX-generation Displaylink chip for video, driver support for this does not exist and is not planned by the producer in the near future.

I repeat: although Displaylink claims to support Linux in their FAQ, the latest generation does NOT support Linux

http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1748

But the NIC and usb ports work out of the box, so if you want an expensive usb-hub/NIC, go ahead.

USB2-based docks with displayport should be supported, though.

Comment: TL;DR http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu

Comment: @codeitagile That is not a summary of my post, it is rather a different answer. I would suggest you post is as such, then other people can upvote it

Comment: I hereby confer all/any upvotes to your answer :)

Comment: I'm surprised by this comment I have been using the Dell 3100 for over 12months with Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works including 2 external displays. This is using my Dell e7470

Answer (score 7):

The DVI out on the dock seems to require some USB-3.0 DisplayPort driver support which is currently missing in the Linux kernel, so it likely *won't* work at the moment.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151463

I haven't managed to get the dock display out working here at least, but the NIC and usb ports work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

With Lenowo OneLink Dock (model DU9026S1) all worked out of box on Ubuntu 13.10, except LAN: you have to add ASIX driver: http://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=downloadsearch&PSNoID=112 - go for USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet and chose chip AX88179 - then install by extracting, make and (sudo) make install, as usually.

Additionally I personally found Sound Switcher to be of great use in connection with this docking: http://yktoo.com/software/indicatorSoundSwitcher...

Answer (score 1):

*martensson's answer from [forums.lenovo.com](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Onelink-Dock-and-Linux-support/td-p/1346267)*

One Link doc works out of the box working:

- HDMI
- Sound (depending on your device change soundcard output)
- USB (front and back)

Additional drivers required:

- Ethernet

Answer (score 0):

The best thing will be to check it with a bootable CD/DVD. I know that USB 3.0 will work on ubuntu cuz it works here for me. But I have to add that I had problem using Linux on Lenovo on older hardware. So I would rather stick to HP or Fujitsu Siemens. But aks if you could check if it works and if it doesnt you just send it back?

Comment: So, you do have that docking from Lenovo? Are you using both DVI ports and it works fine?

Comment: Nope - Sorry - do not have it. But I checked older Lenovo hardware cuz I am an IBM Thinkpad fan. But I was dissapointed about the Linux support of those. So please try for yourself. I just know that generelly USB 3.0 is supported in Ubuntu 12.04 and even older Ubuntus.