# DisplayLink USB 3.0 Not working on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, xorg, displaylink

I noticed this might be yet another DisplayLink outcry - but I thought I give it a go anyway. So the usual story - I have got a DisplayLink adaptor Kensington USB3.0 Video Adapter, and doesn't look like is ever going to work.

It is reorganised when I plug it in.

```
#uname -r
3.13.0-35-generic

# dmesg

[52049.856134] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[52049.989282] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=430f
[52049.989290] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[52049.989295] usb 2-2: Product: Kensington USB3.0 Video Adapter
[52049.989299] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[52049.989304] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 10024214
[52059.384628] usbcore: registered new interface driver udlfb
[52402.886345] usbcore: deregistering interface driver udlfb
[52418.187053] usbcore: registered new interface driver udlfb
[53522.914146] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] CACHE_ERROR - ch 2 [Xorg[1276]] subc 0 mthd 0x0060 data 0xbeef0201
```

I have blacklisted `udl` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf` and removed removed `udlfb` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf`.

I have also manually loaded the `udlfb` driver.

```
# modprobe udlfb

[52418.187053] usbcore: registered new interface driver udlfb
```

Ok so basically I am not moving forward with this - because when I do;

```
# ls /dev | grep fb
```

`fb0` is the only device block found - which indicates to me that udlfb is not detecting the device. `udevadm info` on fb0 reveals - it is the main laptop screen.

```
# udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fb0)

 looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/graphics/fb0':
    KERNEL=="fb0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="graphics"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{pan}=="0,0"
    ATTR{name}=="nouveaufb"
    ATTR{mode}==""
    ATTR{console}==""
    ATTR{blank}==""
    ATTR{modes}=="U:1440x900p-0"
    ATTR{state}=="0"
    ATTR{bits_per_pixel}=="32"
    ATTR{cursor}==""
    ATTR{rotate}=="0"
    ATTR{stride}=="7680"
    ATTR{virtual_size}=="1920,1080"
```

I currently have 1 provider and that is the main screeen.

```
# xrandr --listproviders

Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x65 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:nouveau
```

Digging through `/sys/class/graphics`I noticed `fbcon` with this settings:

```
  looking at device '/devices/virtual/graphics/fbcon':
    KERNEL=="fbcon"
    SUBSYSTEM=="graphics"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{cursor_blink}=="0"
    ATTR{rotate}=="0"
```

Let me also mentioned that I have tried `udl` with `udlfb` blacklisted with no joy neither.

OK so long story short - Is anyone managed to get similar DisplayLink USB 3.0 Adaptor working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update August 2015**

3 years after releasing the chipset, [Displaylink has released beta versions of a driver to support the DL3XXX chip generation under Ubuntu 14.04](http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64049). I leave the following content as original reply to the questions.

Please see:

- [DisplayLink Ubuntu Driver Download](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) and
- [How to install DisplayLink software on Ubuntu](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu) on the DisplayLink website

**Old information below**

The USB3.0 Displaylink devices do *NOT*  support Linux

In particular, this includes the Displaylink DL3XXX-generation and newer.

Displaylink has no intention to make a driver in foreseeable future. See this [thread](http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1748).

Wim of Displaylink wrote on 08-17-2012:

> We don't have any ETAs at the moment, and still looking at the best path to do this. One issue is that the DL-3000 supports content protection and we need to ensure this remains secure under an open source environment.

This was also discussed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185543/has-anyone-tried-the-lenovo-usb-3-0-dock-on-ubuntu/258697#258697) answer.
More related questions here: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360457/where-can-i-download-a-dl-4000-chipset-driver-for-13-04/394118#394118)

**EDIT: July 2015**

It seems that USB3.0 support for Linux might come in Q3 2015, as announced [here](http://displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?p=77618&postcount=177)
(Thanks NecLimDul)

Comment: Shame init! bunch of Linux users out there with one of these devices on their desk and can't use it.

Comment: This is updated to Q3 of 2015
http://displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?p=77618&postcount=177

Comment: It should be updated again: http://www.displaylink.com/for-business/common_questions.php mentions support for Ubuntu 14.04, linking to a package at http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php

Comment: Installation instructions are at http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu

Comment: I am now using two docking stations (HP Port Replicator and Dell D3100 Docking Station) on a Dell Precision M4500 laptop at the same time; each has a display attached; both displays work, thanks to [DisplayLink's driver for Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php), and I can position them with the standard *System Settings ... -> Displays* widget. 3D acceleration probably won't work, but I don't need that right now. Not that the laptop doesn't support USB 3.0 so I don't know if it works with USB 3.0.

Comment: @Reinier Post Thanks for the comments, I updated my original answer to reflect this new development.

Comment: @noleti: Thanks, I've shortened it a little (I have tested the driver and it works for me).

Comment: This answer is really obsolete now!

Comment: Update: after my regular dist-upgrade, X kept crashing. The only fix was to boot an older kernel (3.16.0-51 instead of 53).

Answer (score 3):

Displaylink just released a Linux driver for USB 3 devices:
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php

I tested it under Ubuntu 15.04 with Dell's USB3-Ethernet/VGA/HDMI adapter and it kind of worked, although the recognized display resolution was too low. Also, I have to re-run the installation script after every reboot

Comment: I have installed it - but still no joy. Can't even see activity of it in `dmesg`.

Comment: It works for me. with Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrading the kernel (it is 3.16 now). I don't need to rerun the installation script.

Comment: With compiz, it forgets to update the screen after a keystroke, at least on my computer, which makes the displays pretty hard to work with. Solution: start up with metacity instead (*GNOME Metacity Flashback* in the Ubuntu Unity launcher).

Comment: I installed the driver on ubuntu 14.04 with kernel version 3.19 but still hdmi does not work for me on  Dell XPS 13